# empty string plus an int?

Tags: c++, string, int

Here is part of my code:

```
//num is an int
string s = "" + num;
```

When I run this in Xcode on a Macbook, s will be assigned to a strange string.
Can any one explain this to me?
I am really confused.
Thanks.

Comment: XCode uses Clang by default AFAIK. *warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-int]*

Comment: `""` is a string literal, which decays into a pointer, so you're actually doing pointer arithmetic here yielding [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume `string` refers to the `std::string` type, declared in the standard header `<string>`.     You haven't given that as context - technically, from information you have given it could be some preceding `typedef` or a macro.

The explanation as to why

```
string s = "" + num;
```

gives a "strange string" is that `""` is represented in memory as a `const` array of one `char` that has the value zero.   In the expression `"" + num`, the `""` is converted to a pointer (equal to the address of that `char` with value zero), and `+ num` then gives the address of some location in memory, `num` characters after.

If `num` is non-zero, that memory address may not exist, or (if it exists) might contain arbitrary data.

In any event, that pointer is passed to the constructor of `std::string` (in order to construct `s`).  That constructor starts at the address given, and keeps copying data into the `std::string` until it happens to find a character with value zero.   The characters in between could be anything - they are whatever happens to be at that memory location.

Formally, the C++ standard describes all this (accessing data via a bad pointer) as undefined behaviour.  That means the C++ standard says nothing about what result is permitted, so any result is allowed.    It could result in strange data in your string.   The operating system might detect your program accessing memory it shouldn't, and forceably terminate your program.    It could reformat your hard drive and reinstall your operating system.

Assuming you just want to write `num` to a string (e.g. `num` with value `42` results in a string like `"42"`), then the usual technique is to convert `num` to a `std::string`.   For example;

```
 std::string s = to_string(num);   // C++11 or later
```

or

```
 #include <sstream>            //  pre_C++11 (albeit valid in C++11)
 std::ostringstream ostr;
 ostr << num;
 std::string s(ostr.str());
```

Comment: You forgot to tell that demons might fly out of his/her nose. ;)

Comment: That relies on specific hardware, firmware, and wetware support.  :-)

Comment: So does reinstalling the OS on the fly. ;)

Comment: Thank you. Your great explanation solved all my confusion.@Peter

Comment: @Pixelchemist Luckily I did't write to that address, just printing it out. Maybe I should try to reboot and see if everything ok.

Comment: To be precise, it was a C++11 example.   I'll update in a moment with a pre-C++11 example.

Comment: @Xing: You were dereferencing multiple invalid pointers and you read from their memory locations - that qualifies for a ride to undefined behaviourland.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = std::to_string(num);
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were getting undesirable answer is the arithmetic addition of `num` to the empty string `s`, which is basically like pointer addition in `C` language.

See the examples for better explanation:

**Eg. 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 0;

    string s = "1234567890" + num;
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** 1234567890

**Eg. 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 1;

    string s = "1234567890" + num;
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** 234567890

**Eg. 3:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 4;

    string s = "1234567890" + num;
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**  567890

**Eg. 4:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 8;

    string s = "1234567890" + num;
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** 90

so on..

---

Since, here the string `s` is empty and the `num` has garbage value which leads to undefined result.

Better use `to_string()` before appending `num` to the empty string `s`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 1000;

    string s = "" + to_string(num);
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*The reason you were getting undesirable answer is the unwanted conversion of `int` into `string`.*" No. Your solution is fine, but your rationale is wrong.

Comment: @ildjarn Could you please tell me what changes i'll have to make in my answer in bit of details.

Comment: OK it got it after running on some test cases. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The idea about `std::to_string()` is good, but it unfortunately only works with C++11 and I have seen compilers that do not fully support that aspect though they support C++11. If you can use it, use it.

If it does not work try this:

```
#include <sstream>

...

int num = 5;
float rNum = 63.2;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << num;
ss << rNum;

std::string s;
ss >> s;

cout << s << endl;
```

You are going to get the float and int values formatted to one string. Actually I think you are better off with stringstreams if you have multiple variables get formatted. Pull them out as string with `ss >> s` and you are done!

Comment: I'd suggest to have `auto s(ss.str());` (if possible) or `std::string s(ss.str());`, rather than using `operator>>`.

Comment: What is the difference? Is it technically the same and refer to elegance or why is ```std::string s(ss.str());``` better?

Comment: 1. It is semantically different if `ss` contains spaces [see example](http://ideone.com/CRnH7i). 
2. It is probably more efficient because `operator>>` of `std::basic_istream` and `std::basic_string` performs several checks in order to avoid reading out of bounds / past EOF etc. If there is no special overload for the `stringstream`s, those check will be performed. The `basic_stringbuf` class however, usually holds a `basic_string` which can (fully or partly - if overallocated) be returned by `str()`.